# jQuery's attr() fails when debugging step by step in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, debugging

I've found some strange code behavior while debugging the next code in Chrome:

```
1. $('.btn-info').click(function(){
2.         console.log("Category ID: " + $(this).attr("category_id"));
3.         var categoryId = $(this).attr("category_id") ;
4.         console.log("CategoryID: " + categoryId);
5. });
```

When I put a break point on line 3 and run the script with a debugger I get the message `Category ID: {some value}` printed in console as expected. However continuing by stepping over the line 3 and inspecting the value of `categoryId` shows the variable's value to be `NaN` by somewhat reason, so after stepping over the line 4 I get in console `Category ID:`.

What interesting is that if I run the same script without break points I get both messages `Category ID: {some value}` printed in console as expected.

Could anyone explain such a strange behavior, please?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please post the HTML part?

Answer (score 0):

problems like this when debugging usually happens when something else is changing the value, for example something like

```
var val=1;
$.get(..., function(){
  val=2
});
console.log(val);
```

if u add break point on console.log() the program probably will have enough time to complete get and run the callback. but with out break point it is usually val=1 in output.

of course it is not that obvious, but look in callbacks, and u will find the problem